# How to retrieve child table records from parent in hibernate?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, exception

I am working on `Hibernate` where i have two tables like `Country` and `City`

**Country :**

`Id int(20) NOT NULL,
  CountryName int(30) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (Id)`

**City :**

`CId int(20) NOT NULL,
  CityName varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  State varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  ADD CONSTRAINT`cid`FOREIGN KEY (`Country`) REFERENCES`id`(`Id`);`

- Means `City` Many-to-One mapped with `Country`

Now i need to access the `City` details from `Country`

- I created already 'Country.hbm.xml'
- I created already 'City.hbm.xml'

**Query:**

`select a.countryName,a.cities.cityName,a.cities.state  from  Country as a`

**Query Result**

`org.hibernate.QueryException: illegal attempt to dereference colection[country0_.Id.cities] with element property reference[cityName][select a.countryName,a.cities.cityName,a.cities.state  from  Country as a]`

I don't know why it is showing this exception..., if anyone knows, it will a great pleasure for me..!!

**Note:** I am retrieving child details from parent

Answer (score 0):

In your Country entity define a @OneToMany mapping for City like this. i.e One Country can have many cities.

```
@OneToMany(targetEntity = City.class, cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
private List<City> cites;
```

Then once your load the Country, just call country.getCities() which would return all the City of that Country.